# Grails 1.3.7 -Where's the build.xml?

Tags: grails, ant, ivy

This is Grails 1.3.7, and not Grails 2.x. Very important because there are all sorts of nice features in Grails 2.x that would really help us out, but don't seem to be available in this version. The developer is attempting to upgrade, but it might take a while.

Straight to the heart of the issue. We build with Jenkins and Ivy. We have our grails app using our local Maven repository, but it uses the default `$HOME/.ivy/cache` for the cache. We need some way to redefine it.

We found this tidbit in the 1.3.7 documentation which seems to give us what we may need:

> ### 4.5 Ant and Maven
>
> [...]
>
> #### Ant Integration
>
> When you create a Grails application via the create-app command, ***Grails automatically creates an Apache Ant build.xml file for you*** containing the following targets:

Sounds great. However, when I run `grails create-app foo`, I could not find a `build.xml` file in my `foo` project.

Is there something I need to do in order to create this `build.xml` that the documentation isn't telling me?

And, yes. I know about `grails.dependency.cache.dir`, but that's not introduced to Release 2.0.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the command `grails integrate-with --ant` in order to generate `build.xml`.  Find the same [here](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Command%20Line/integrate-with.html) in detail specific to Grails 1.3.7.

Comment: That works great! The big problem is that we move the standard Ivy cache because we clean the entire cache before each Jenkins build, and we do parallel builds in Jenkins. If two projects are running sharing the same cache one project will delete the cache while another is using it.